# "RES" DOMDocument XML not working on server and working local

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

this code works locally but not on the server.

The server php version is 5.4 and the local 5.3.

```
<?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $xml = file_get_contents('http://www.directe.cat/sindica.php?lloc=acn&comarca=Alt%20Urgell');
    $rss->loadXML($xml);
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 4;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['title'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
        echo '<small><em>Escrit: '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
        echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Check phpinfo() on the server and check the ini value of allow_url_fopen, which needs to equal On in order for file_get_contents to function with http/https:// URIs.

Comment: Thanks this was the solution

Answer (score 0):

Add this below line in your .htaccess file. So it will work.

php_value allow_url_fopen On